# preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php

```
class Check {

    private static $Data;
    private static $Format;

    public static function Email($Email) {
        self::$Data = (string) $Email;
        self::$Format = "/[a-z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-z0-9_\.\-]*[a-z0-9_\.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/";

        if (preg_match(self::$Data, self::$Format)):
            return true;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    }

}
```

Acima meu código onde uso, o `pre_match` está dando erro:

```
Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Pesquisei sobre mas nao consegui resolver.
O que estou fazendo errado ?

Comment: quais os dados de entrada?

Comment: email eu@gmail.com , no caso o $Data esta recebendo esse email.

Comment: não se pode te ajudar, mas para validação de email eu costumo usar filter_input($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Comment: obrigado, consegui com tua dica ;)

Answer (score 6):

Você está invertendo os parâmetros, uma lida no [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) evita estes problemas.

> [`preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

A ordem correta seria esta:

```
 preg_match(self::$Format,self::$Data)
```

Aproveitando, isso aqui não faz muito sentido:

```
if (preg_match(self::$Data, self::$Format)):
    return true;
else:
    return false;
endif;
```

Se é pra retornar `true` ou `false` já retorne o valor diretamente, não existe razão pra `if`.

```
class Check {

    private static $Data;
    private static $Format;

    public static function Email($Email) {
        self::$Data = (string) $Email;
        self::$Format = "/[a-z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-z0-9_\.\-]*[a-z0-9_\.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/";

        return preg_match(self::$Format,self::$Data);
    }
}
```

Vale dizer ainda que as variáveis neste caso poderiam ser locais (só do método, e não da classe).

Conforme o Rafael mencionou nos comentários, se preferir o PHP já tem uma alternativa pronta para isso, o que é recomendável no lugar do seu RegEx (que por sinal não respeita o padrão válido de emails, negando coisa que não deve).

```
filter_input($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Comment: Bacco Obrigado pela aula, realmente tu esta certo, não me atentei a leitura básica. E o meu if que não havia necessidade, cara,obrigado mesmo. :D

Comment: @DiegoGo acostume sempre a ver o manual do PHP, que evita esses problemas e vc não fica sofrendo dependendo de dar sorte de alguém responder na hora que você estiver precisando. Como o PHP tem uma ordem muito estranha de parâmetros, até quem tem experiência precisa "tirar a teima" de vez em quando. Estamos aqui pra ajudar, mas quanto mais você conseguir resolver essas coisas por conta própria, menos tempo fica preso em problemas desse tipo. Mas quando precisar, pergunte, claro.